# Fundamental group a collection of six 2-spheres touching pairwise in a cyclic order, and each touching a common plane.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Find the fundamental group of the space comprising a collection of six 2-spheres
touching pairwise in a cyclic order, and each touching a common plane.

Touching means having one point in common. I am thinking about using Van Kampen's Theorem... But having trouble executing it...

[image]

Comment: Any other details need clarification?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem!  My approach would be to deform the space through a sequence of homotopy equivalences into a space whose fundamental group is easily computed, instead of using van Kampen's theorem directly.

First, wherever two spheres, or a sphere and the plane, are touching, I elongate the contact point into a line segment.  This space deformation retracts onto our original space, and so has the same homotopy type.  Then since the plane is contractible, I can contract away the plane to a single point.  At this point, I get something like the following:
[image: Spheres on a plane]

Each sphere is connected to a line segment at three places.  Pick a contractible arc on each sphere passing through the three contact points and contract away each arc. We now get a space consisting of a graph on seven vertices with a sphere attached to six of the vertices.

Now contract a spanning tree of the graph.  We end up with a space homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^6 S^1 \vee \bigvee_{j=1}^6 S^2$.

Hopefully you can continue on from this point and compute the fundamental group of this space.  Write back if anything is unclear!